# PHP JSON to JavaScript Array

Tags: php, javascript, json

Is there any good way to pass an PHP Array to my JavaScript as JS Array?

if have this PHP Array:

```
array('XYZ' => 1, 'ABC' => 2);
```

and i need in my javascript, to print out some plots

```
var myData = [['XYZ', 1], ['ABC', 2]];
```

**Problem:**

If i do console.log(); i get an object and not an array?

I think i have to parse the JSON in my JavaScript part of the application or? Is there any JQuery Plugin to convert this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want an array as the result of the json_encode you have to present it as non-associative array.

Try something like this:

```
<?php 
$a=array('XYZ' => 1, 'ABC' => 2);
$r=array();
foreach ($a as $k=>$v)
{
   $r[]=array($k, $v);
}
echo json_encode($r);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do `echo json_encode($myArray);` it will echo out:

```
    {
       "XYZ": "1",
       "ABC": "2"
    }
```

Which you can use in js:

On your php page you can do:

```
<script>

   var myJson = <?php echo json_encode($myArray) ?>;

   console.log(myJson);

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks but console.log says "object" wich is ok, but i need this[[]] Array format for an Plugin.

Comment: You should add a semicolon: echo json_encode($myArray);

Answer (score 0):

you can use `json_encode(array)` at php side to conver php array to json. And then you can directly assign it to a js variable like var `jsarray = jsonencodedphparray`

Answer (score 0):

Jquery has it built in.

in PHP - Echo the response in json format  echo json_encode(arr);

In the javascript - parse the json into an object   var obj = $.parseJSON(response)